# left join where b.key is null by two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables.

```
  table_1       | table_2
id col_1 | col_2 | col_1 | col_2
1  1     | B     | 1     | B
2  1     | C     | 3     | C
3  1     | D     | 5     | D
....
```

I write this query

```
SELECT *
    FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.col_1 = t2.col_1
    WHERE t1.col_1 = 1
        AND (
            t2.col_1 IS NULL
            AND t2.col_1 != 'B'
            )
```

I want get this result.

```
table_1          |
id col_1 | col_2 |
2  1     | C     |
3  1     | D     |
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

**Update question**

Table 1 - PriceItems, Table 2 - BlockedPrices, col1 - Code, col2 - Brand.

I want to get all PriceItems current code and all brands exept codes from BlockesPrices.

Comment: `AND t2.col_1 IS NULL AND t2.col_1 != 'B'` - I don't understand your logic.  If it's `NULL`, it naturally won't be `'B'`.  Can you explain your logic in words?

Comment: Table 1 - PriceItems, Table 2 - BlockedPrices, col1 - Code, col2 Brand. I want to get all PriceItems current code and all brands exept codes from BlockesPrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're looking for:

```
Select      t1.*
From        table_1 t1
Left Join   table_2 t2  On  t1.col_1 = t2.col_1
                        And t2.col_1 != 'B'
Where       t1.col_1 = 1
And         t2.col_1 Is Not Null
```

As I understand your question, you're looking to do a `LEFT JOIN` on the second table, but have the case where `t2.col_1 = 'B'` excluded from your final result.

In this case, you'll need to move the condition `t2.col_1 = 'B'` to your `ON` clause to have records that don't match both of the `LEFT JOIN` conditions come back as `NULL`.

The reason you might have seen strange results is due to the `AND t2.col_1 != 'B'` condition in your `WHERE` clause.  This causes the filter to happen *after* the `LEFT JOIN`, which will further filter those results (thus, effectively transforming the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

**Edit, question changed:**

Based on the new information in the question, you are using the second table as an *exclusion* table, and want to remove the results from the first table that appear in the second.

For this, you don't need a `JOIN` at all, you can just do it with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
Select  *
From    PriceItems  P
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    BlockedPrices   B
    Where   P.Code = B.Code
    And     P.Brand = B.Brand
)
And     P.Code = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for unswer. But this query doesn't work. I add comment under my question.

Comment: I want to get all items from table_1 with table_1.col_1 = 1 and col_2 = ('B', 'C', etc) exept only items from BlockesPrices.

Comment: @Sivard Updated.  You can remove the `And P.Code = 1` to not restrict it to that particular code (as indicated in your question).

Answer (score 0):

This produces the output you want and it seems much simpler:

```
select t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2
from t1 join
     t2
     on t2.col2 = t1.col2
where t1.col1 <> 'B';
```

Strictly speaking, the `join` is not necessary, but I assume your real problem is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You only want results from table_1, so you don't even need a join.

```
select * 
from table_1 t1
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from table_2 t2
  where t1.col_1 = t2.col_1 
    and t2.col_2 = t2.col_2
)
```

You can provide any other `where` condition in the inner select statement to specify what type of match should disqualify table_1 records from being listed.

For example, you could add `and t2.price > 2000` to the inner `where` condition to disqualify all records from table_1 that have matching record in table_2 with price above 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is several years old .. but there are typos in the OP:

> AND t2.col_1 != 'B'
>
> Clearly, this should have been "t2.col_2"

Regardless, the answer seems simple enough:

```
select t1.*
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2
on t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
where t2.col1 is null
```

Results:

| ident | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | C |
| 3 | 1 | D |

See solution:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/58e05/15

Schema Build:

```
create table table_1 
( ident int,
 col1 int,
 col2 char(1)
 );

create table table_2 
( col1 int,
 col2 char(1)
 );

insert into table_1 (ident, col1, col2)
values (1, 1,'B');
insert into table_1 (ident, col1, col2)
values (2, 1,'C');
insert into table_1 (ident, col1, col2)
values (3, 1,'D');

insert into table_2 (col1, col2)
values (1,'B');
insert into table_2 (col1, col2)
values (3,'C');
insert into table_2 (col1, col2)
values (5,'D');
```